# Add UIView from another controller to a UIView with autolayout

Tags: ios, uiview, containers, autolayout

I try to switch UIViews from differnt UIViewControllers to my main container view controller inside of a UIViewController. The problem is the new UIView is not resizing to the container view size. I tried to do it with this function, but still not working. In one of the UIViews I have a UIWebView inside.

```
-(void) showViewWithIndex: (NSInteger) index{

    //remove old stuff
    [_containerView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];

    UIViewController *controllerToShow = _settingsController[index];

    if (controllerToShow) {

        NSLog(@"main height: %f width: %f", _containerView.frame.size.height, _containerView.frame.size.width);

        UIView *controllerViewToShow = controllerToShow.view;

        //clear constaints
        [controllerViewToShow removeConstraints:controllerViewToShow.constraints];
        [_containerView removeConstraints: _containerView.constraints];

        controllerViewToShow.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

        [_containerView addSubview: controllerToShow.view];

        [_containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                                   constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[controllerViewToShow]-|"
                                   options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing
                                   metrics:nil
                                   views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(controllerViewToShow)]];

        [_containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                                   constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[controllerViewToShow]-|"
                                   options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing
                                   metrics:nil
                                   views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(controllerViewToShow)]];


        //update all views:
        [_containerView layoutIfNeeded];
        [_containerView needsUpdateConstraints];

        [controllerViewToShow layoutIfNeeded];
        [controllerViewToShow needsUpdateConstraints];


        NSLog(@"controllerViewToShow width: %f height: %f", controllerViewToShow.frame.size.height, controllerViewToShow.frame.size.width);

    }

}
```

Comment: yes this also doesn't have any effect... its still the same size like in the storyboard.

Comment: also not working. I think with autolayout u shouldn't use frame stuff...

Comment: found the problem I guess but I am not allowed here to post it now... thanks stackoverflow:

The UIView I want to add already has some constraints:

subview constraints: (
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xd144fc0 V:[UIWebView:0x9aae9a0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x9c3a750 )>",
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xd144ff0 H:|-(0)-[UIWebView:0x9aae9a0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x9c3a750 )>",

Comment: "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0xd145160 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0xd144a80(0)]>",
        "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0xd141c00 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0xd144a80]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x9c3a750 )>",
        "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0xd141480 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0xd144c90(0)]>",
        "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0xd140ea0 _UILayoutGuide:0xd144c90.bottom == UIView:0x9c3a750.bottom>"